# Web Development on Ubuntu

Tags: server, php

I recently started learning Ubuntu, and i'll like to know if it is possible for me to practice and develop Web Applications with PHP/MySQL and HTML/CSS on Ubuntu, develop Linux based Applications/GUI? Also will this be enough for me to master Linux Server configuration? Then is there a manual for Ubuntu? For example www.php.net as for PHP.

I'll be most delighted with your honest answers and opinions.

Comment: Please, ask one question per time next time. Open multiple posts for multiple questions with different subjects.

Answer (score 2):

**Webdevelopment**

You can develop web applications the way like you would do on any other OS.
Install [LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Default you've to store all webfiles in `/var/www` folder.

You can use the default editor Gedit, but their are enought ([better](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CKkEEIwQMAE&url=http://www.sublimetext.com/2&ei=FXTQT6jAOYWb8QOOpInLDA&usg=AFQjCNEkh9fEo4zf4j-B6LPgSfFGxGaNFQ&sig2=uHInJrwed7Guugp8qpKrSw)) editors.

**Ubuntu Server**

[Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html)

**Ubuntu Desktop**

[Ubuntu desktop help](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/index.html)

[Community Help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although i havent vistited the links you gave. What language is need for developing desktop apps for Linux.

Comment: C/C++/Java/Python/Ruby almost any language can be used for gui development on linux.

Comment: I do like me some Sublime Text. :)
In my opinion, really good for web dev. Improvements for better css autocomplete is coming soon to dev release.

Comment: Have you seen all the packages? I love Auto reload, SFTP and Aditional PHP snippets

Answer (score 0):

Install xampp for webserver (php, phpmyadmin, apache2).

Install Eclipse PDT for php IDE (the best free IDE AFAK).

Create a folder in your home (eg: web_dev) and put all your sites into it instead of /var/www by this command:

```
ln -s /home/you/Web_dev /var/www
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Can you explain why do you suggest this step?